# Show the set of strictly increasing, continuous functions $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is not an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is the question: Show the subset $A \subset C[0,1]$ of all strictly increasing functions $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is not an open set. Note the distance function here is the supremum of the difference, or sup{$|f(x)|; x \in [0,1]$}.

I'm honestly stumped about this question. I know a set A is open if $intA = A$ and the interior is the largest open set in A. But if I want to show it isn't open, does that mean I need to find a ball of some radius which only contains points in A but is not in A? How would I go about finding such a thing especially given that this is a set of functions rather than numbers?

Comment: Intuitively, you need to show that for some continuous, increasing function $f$, there exist non-increasing functions "arbitrarily close" to $f$. (In fact, this is true for every continuous, increasing function.) To make your question precise, you need to specify how you're measuring "closeness". (Presumably the supremum of the difference...?)

Comment: It would suffice to show there are continuous functions  arbitrarily close to $f(x)=x$ that are not strictly increasing.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Yes, I'm using the supremum of the difference. Let me add that into the question.

Comment: Hint (following David Mitra's comment): Imagine you're drawing the graph $y = x$ when something startles you just a little.... Does that suggest a way of defining a sequence of continuous, non-increasing functions whose limit is $f(x) = x$?

Comment: I'm a little thrown off by "startles". If such a sequence did exist, wouldn't at some point in the sequence, it become strictly increasing?

Comment: Actually I think I got it. Thank you to @Andrew D. Hwang.

Comment: Also thank you to @David Mitra!

Comment: One last question though, why is it enough to show that such a sequence exists?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a strictly increasing continuous function on $[0,1]$. Suppose $\varepsilon >0$ are given. Then, there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then, defining $g(x)$ piecewise by $g(x)= f(\frac{1}{n})$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ otherwise. For any $x\in [0,\frac{1}{n})$ we obtain $g(x)-f(x)= f(\frac{1}{n}) - f(x) < f(\frac{1}{n}) -f(0)  < \varepsilon$. Obviously $g$ is not strictly increasing on $[0,1]$ and $g$ is in $B(f,\varepsilon)$.